# How to make a loop wait for an event listener?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a coin toss game where you set the number of games you want to play, and then choose head or tails for each iteration. But my `for` loop doesen't wait for the eventListener and the loop is over before the user even clicked once.

```
function play(){
    head.addEventListener("click", choice);
    tails.addEventListener("click", choice);
}
function choice(e){
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() *2);
    console.log(random);
    let clicked = e.target;
    e.target.style.border = "3px solid green";
    head.removeEventListener("click", choice);
    tails.removeEventListener("click", choice);
    if (random == 0){
        result.src = head.src;
        result.style.height = "100%";
        if(result.src == clicked.src){
            result.style.border = "3px solid green";
            
        }
        else{
            result.style.border = "3px solid red";
            
        }
    }
    if (random == 1){
        result.src = tails.src;
        result.style.height = "100%";
        if(result.src == clicked.src){
            result.style.border = "3px solid green";
            
        }
        else{
            result.style.border = "3px solid red";
            
        }
    }
    setTimeout(refresh, 3000);
    function refresh(){
        result.style.border = "none";
        clicked.style.border = "none";
    }

}

function wait(){
for (let i = 0; i < playAmount; i++){
    console.log(i);
    play();
}
}
wait();
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you should not use a loop. You should call the next iteration after the user interaction.

Comment: Instead of working with loops, this use case suggests to use callbacks or promises.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem without for loop.
Just take a variable count = 0 and flag = false at the starting .
Now just follow the program as under

```
var count = 0 , flag = true ;
    flag&&head.addEventListener("click", choice);
    flag&&tails.addEventListener("click", choice);
function choice(e){
    if(count>=playAmount)flag=false;
    else count++;
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() *2);
    console.log(random);
    let clicked = e.target;
    e.target.style.border = "3px solid green";
    head.removeEventListener("click", choice);
    tails.removeEventListener("click", choice);
    if (random == 0){
        result.src = head.src;
        result.style.height = "100%";
        if(result.src == clicked.src){
            result.style.border = "3px solid green";
            
        }
        else{
            result.style.border = "3px solid red";
            
        }
    }
    if (random == 1){
        result.src = tails.src;
        result.style.height = "100%";
        if(result.src == clicked.src){
            result.style.border = "3px solid green";
            
        }
        else{
            result.style.border = "3px solid red";
            
        }
    }
    setTimeout(refresh, 3000);
    function refresh(){
        result.style.border = "none";
        clicked.style.border = "none";
    }

}
```

I hope this solves your problem .

Answer (score 0):

Let us go through some key parts of your implementation(refer to my comments inline)

```
function play() { 
  head.addEventListener("click", choice);
  tails.addEventListener("click", choice);
  
  //the above 2 lines add a click event listener to the two buttons,
  //that is, whenever these 2 buttons are clicked,
  //the function `choice` will be called
}
function choice(e) {
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  console.log(random);
  let clicked = e.target;
  e.target.style.border = "3px solid green";
  head.removeEventListener("click", choice);
  tails.removeEventListener("click", choice);
  
  //the above 2 lines remove the click event listener from the two buttons
  //that is, now the function `choice` will not be called at button click 
  
  if (random == 0) {
    result.src = head.src;
    result.style.height = "100%";
    if (result.src == clicked.src) {
      result.style.border = "3px solid green";
    } else {
      result.style.border = "3px solid red";
    }
  }
  if (random == 1) {
    result.src = tails.src;
    result.style.height = "100%";
    if (result.src == clicked.src) {
      result.style.border = "3px solid green";
    } else {
      result.style.border = "3px solid red";
    }
  }
  setTimeout(refresh, 3000);
  function refresh() {
    result.style.border = "none";
    clicked.style.border = "none";
  }
}

function wait() {
  for (let i = 0; i < playAmount; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    play();
    //calls the play function `playAmount` times
  }
}
wait();
```

Now let us discuss the problems with this approach

1. Calling the `play()` function `playAmount` times from `wait()` (tries to) binds(adds) the *click* event listener to both the buttons `playAmount` times, ***but*** adding the  same function `n` times as an event listener is same as adding it once, reference : [addEventListener docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
2. once `choice` is called, you remove the event listeners from both the buttons (remember , the event listeners were only bound once in a loop in the `wait()` function),
   now with no event listener bound on the buttons, the buttons wont register the event ***click*** anymore.

The below implementation should work for you:

```
let numberOfTurnsTaken = 0;
//add a global variable to count the turns taken

function play() { 
  head.addEventListener("click", choice);
  tails.addEventListener("click", choice);
  //bind the event listeners
}
function choice(e) {
  numberOfTurnsTaken++;
  //increment the turns
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  console.log(random);
  let clicked = e.target;
  e.target.style.border = "3px solid green";

  //remove the event listeners only when the turns are over and we are `handling` the last turn
  if(numberOfTurnsTaken == playAmount){
    head.removeEventListener("click", choice);
    tails.removeEventListener("click", choice);
  }
  
  if (random == 0) {
    result.src = head.src;
    result.style.height = "100%";
    if (result.src == clicked.src) {
      result.style.border = "3px solid green";
    } else {
      result.style.border = "3px solid red";
    }
  }
  if (random == 1) {
    result.src = tails.src;
    result.style.height = "100%";
    if (result.src == clicked.src) {
      result.style.border = "3px solid green";
    } else {
      result.style.border = "3px solid red";
    }
  }
  setTimeout(refresh, 3000);
  function refresh() {
    result.style.border = "none";
    clicked.style.border = "none";
  }
}

//set things rolling by binding click event handlers on the buttons
play();


//the loop is no longer needed
//function wait() {
//  for (let i = 0; i < playAmount; i++) {
//    console.log(i);
//    play();
//  }
//}
//wait();
```